# Insert missing numbers between 1 and the Maximum Number CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The column MissingNumber is the maximum number and the myID is the Identity column. IF 1 is the minimum number for all of them is there a SQL query that i could use to duplicate a sequentially from 1 to the maximum numbers partitioned by myID.

```
DECLARE @NumbersTable TABLE
(
myID int NOT NULL,
OtherColumn Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
MissingNumber INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @NumbersTable VALUES
(1,'Apple', 10)
INSERT INTO @NumbersTable VALUES
(2,'Orange', 5)
INSERT INTO @NumbersTable VALUES
(3,'Kiwi', 15)
INSERT INTO @NumbersTable VALUES
(4,'Mango', 4)
INSERT INTO @NumbersTable VALUES
(5,'Strawberry', 8)

SELECT * FROM @NumbersTable
```

Results

```
myID        OtherColumn          MissingNumber
----------- -------------------- -------------
1           Apple                10
2           Orange               5
3           Kiwi                 15
4           Mango                4
5           Strawberry           8

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Output for myID 1 and 2( apples and oranges)

```
myID        OtherColumn          MissingNumber
----------- -------------------- -------------
1           Apple                1
1           Apple                2
1           Apple                3
1           Apple                4
1           Apple                5
1           Apple                6
1           Apple                7
1           Apple                8
1           Apple                9
1           Apple                10
2           Orange               1
2           Orange               2
2           Orange               3
2           Orange               4
2           Orange               5
```

Comment: I don't get it. What output do you expect?

Comment: Can you clarify what actually you want to do? show some sample output you want from this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an interesting article and got the answer i need thanx everyone

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/find-missing-date-ranges-in-sql/

```
;WITH cteMyNumber
AS
(
SELECT myID,OtherColumn,MissingNumber
FROM @NumbersTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT myID,OtherColumn,MissingNumber -1
FROM cteMyNumber
WHERE MissingNumber >0
)
SELECT * FROM cteMyNumber
WHERE MissingNumber<>0
ORDER BY myID,MissingNumber
```

Comment: Ok, that works too. As you're using MS SQL you don't need the overhead of a recursive cte if your range is between 1 - 2047 (the range in master..spt_values). In any case setting up a numbers/calendar table might be a good idea.

Comment: @jpw: On the other hand, recursive CTEs do not scale well and using one for larger values may not be a good idea either, so...

Comment: @KipReal: Note that you will need to use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION)` if you expect `MissingNumber` to exceed 100 sometimes.

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah, that was what I was trying to say. That using a fixed numbers table is better than a recursive cte and that `master..spt_values`can be used as such if there is no other number table.

Answer (score 1):

## Numbers Table!

Google around for a numbers table, roll your own, or use [one I made earlier](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql)

```
SELECT NumbersTable.my.ID
     , NumbersTable.OtherColumn
     , numbers.number As MissingNumber
FROM   @NumbersTable As NumbersTable
 INNER
  JOIN dbo.numbers
    ON numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND NumbersTable.MissingNumber
WHERE  NumbersTable.myID IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a number table. If you don't have one already you can use the`master..spt_values`to generate a sequence of numbers:

```
INSERT @NumbersTable (myID, OtherColumn, MissingNumber)
SELECT myID, othercolumn, m.number FROM @NumbersTable n
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT number FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND n.MissingNumber - 1    
    ) m
```

or

```
INSERT @NumbersTable (myID, OtherColumn, MissingNumber)
SELECT myID, OtherColumn, m.number FROM @NumbersTable n
INNER JOIN master..spt_values m ON m.number < n.MissingNumber
WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND m.number > 0
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35715/1)